# iOS 6: What changed that made this View Controller Hierarchy break?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios6

The following is in my AppDelegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

customViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:customViewController];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In the actual XIB, the View is associated with the "File's Owner" and that is my only association there..

XIB Hierarchy:

```
Navigation Controller
    - View Controller - Root View Controller
        -View (Associated with File's Owner)
```

Sorry if I don't understand this, it was working fine on a previously launched app but I understand that does not mean it was correct.

Edit: Sorry here is the error I am getting:

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View < UIView: 0xa192d00; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = < CALayer: 0xa192d60>> is associated with < UIViewController: 0xa195c70>. Clear this association before associating this view with < CustomViewController: 0xa1802a0>.'

Comment: Added, sorry about that.

Comment: in the xib is CustomViewController's view associated with some other navigation controller?

Comment: It is associated with "File's Owner"

Comment: same issue I am facing.... after modalview dismiss

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure your views' interface does not have an extra view controller in its hierarchy. See the screenshots below

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: This solved my problem that was bugging me for 3 weeks. thanks.